# How to use kubernetes pod file in my remote Jenkins job

Tags: shell, jenkins, kubernetes

I have a jenkins server that has access to remote k8 cluster. I need to run a shell script as a part of jenkins job and pass it the file that is inside the remote kubernetes pod.

I don't want to copy the file from k8 pod to jenkins server as the file is huge ~25G.

I tried with creating a variable 'kubectl_variable' with value:

```
kubectl get -f pod:<path to file>
this gives error as:
error: the path "podname:/var/lib/datastorage/dump.txt" cannot be accessed: CreateFile podname:/var/lib/datastorage/dump.txt: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I was thinking of passing this variable to the shell script as:

```
parse.sh ${kubectl_variable}
```

I am not sure if I can achieve this or not.

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You either need to copy the file to Jenkins for it to access it or run the script inside the container that has the file. How did you mount the file inside the pod btw?

Comment: If it is too expensive to copy the remote file, you can instead run a script on the pod. Take a look at [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec).

Comment: Is it possible for you to run shell script from a `Pod` that has this large file and then pass result to Jenkins server ?

Comment: For now, It is not possible to run a script on customer live environment pods as this can cause other resource issues on it.